# How to conditioning a data step in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas, dataset, execute

I'm inside a big `call execute` and I have to do a data step only if a flag variable is `0` and not `1`.
That is, if `flag=1` then the data step begin, otherwise not.
So I should use `IF` outside of a `macro` and outside a data step.
How can I fix?

thanks in advance

Comment: please give an example of the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use macro language, and macro versions of if and then and so on. Try this:

```
%let flag = ; 

*or method/logic such as :into or other to set macro value to 1 or 0;

%macro pre_run_check();
    %if &flag = 1 %then %do;

    *CODE HERE;

    %end;
%mend;

%pre_run_check();
```

28/07/2016: czechraisin edited